# target="_blank" don't show a close button on the opened tab iOS

Tags: html, ios, web, native

I'm writing a HTML anchor tag which will redirect me to a specific link on a new tab.

```
<a href="https://something.com" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

All works good but when I test it on my native iOS app, the link the new tab appears with my link but without a close button on it.
I don't know why it doesn't appear, can someone have any ideea?

Comment: How do you write your iOS app? web view ?